# Lambda versions are incremented even i delete the lambda stack(ie.CFN)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am publishing the NEW lambda version for each of my each lambda function in my cloudformation template using custom resource . This invokes when ever there is an update to the lambda function.

I have two lambda functions in my stack(i.e.`STACK1`) which are created using CFN template. There Arn's are like this .

```
arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:xxxx:function:Pikachuu:1
arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:xxxx:function:Pythachuu:1
```

After few updates to my stack(i.e.'STACK1`) it became like this

```
arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:xxxx:function:Pikachuu:5
arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:xxxx:function:Pythachuu:2
```

Next Step, i had deleted the above stack(i.e.'STACK1`) and created a new stack with different name(i.e.'STACK2`). When i see the created ARN's of the lambda functions they are like this

```
arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:xxxx:function:Pikachuu:6
arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:xxxx:function:Pythachuu:3
```

Even i deleted the stack and created a new one with new name i dont know why these lambda ARN's versions are incremented.

When i digged this issue deep , i had found that it is published based on the `fuctionname` so when i changed the function name then it started with `version 1`. 
Even deleting the stack, is not deleting the versions on the function because of  that when i used the same function name it is taking the functions version.

I also checked the lambdas are present or not in lambda console just to double check whether cloudformation is deleting it or not . Yes, Cloudformation is deleting it.

How can i able to avoid this scenario ??

> BTW: This situation is not occuring when i allow `AWS` to define my
>   lambda function name.

Thanks.
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior can't be changed. After you publish a version, it is **immutable** (that is, it can't be changed). This ensures that the function's consumer will get exactly the same function code and configurations.

> AWS Lambda assigns a monotonically increasing sequence number for
>   versioning, even if the function was deleted and recreated. Version
>   numbers are never reused, even for a function that has been deleted
>   and recreated. This approach means that the consumer of a function
>   version can depend on the executable of that version to never change
>   (except if it's deleted).

See more in AWS lambda version [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/versioning-intro.html)